# CDI Constructor Injection in a JAX-WS web service

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, cdi

I have a JAX-WS webservice deployed to a Java EE 6 container.

I would like to use CDI to inject session beans to this webservice. Up till now I have successfully been doing this using field injection but the company policy is to use constructor based injection. The webservice implementation is NOT a session bean. So is

```
@WebService
public class MyWebservice{

  private ServiceA serviceA;

  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Inject
  public MyWebservice( ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB)
  {
     this.serviceA = serviceA;
     this.serviceB = serviceB;
  }

  public void webMethod1()
  {
     serviceA.doSomething();
     serviceB.doSomething();
  }
}
```

acceptable to CDI?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I must do the same thing.